# Getting array of school values from all objects using JS

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Hello I am new to the JavaScript language.

I have a `table1.data` property that's an array of objects with data about a school like:

```js
{ schoolName: "School 1", telephone: "123456", address: "1st street, 1st road" }
```

Can I perhaps get an array of the telephone values from all the objects using JS? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do it traverse the items in the data, while grabbing the `telephone` field value.

Here is the long-way:

```js
const table1 = {
  data: [
    { schoolName: "School 1", telephone: "(111) 111-1111", address: "1st street" },
    { schoolName: "School 2", telephone: "(222) 222-2222", address: "2nd street" },
    { schoolName: "School 3", telephone: "(333) 333-3333", address: "3rd street" }
  ]
};

const phoneNumbers = [];
for (let i = 0; i < table1.data.length; i++) {
  phoneNumbers.push(table1.data[i].telephone);
}

console.log(phoneNumbers);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Here is the short way:

```js
const table1 = {
  data: [
    { schoolName: "School 1", telephone: "(111) 111-1111", address: "1st street" },
    { schoolName: "School 2", telephone: "(222) 222-2222", address: "2nd street" },
    { schoolName: "School 3", telephone: "(333) 333-3333", address: "3rd street" }
  ]
};

const phoneNumbers = table1.data.map(({ telephone }) => telephone);

console.log(phoneNumbers);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

Comment: Your answers are a down sight more elegant than mine! +1

Comment: this one is feasible as well, thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a `for` loop

```js
let data = [
  {schoolName: "School 1", telephone: "123456", address: "1st street, 1st road"},
  {schoolName: "School 2", telephone: "654321", address: "2nd street, 2nd road"}
];

let telephoneArr = [];
for (const addressObj of data) {
   telephoneArr.push(addressObj.telephone);
};
console.log(telephoneArr);
```

Or you could use `Object.keys`

```js
let data = [
  {schoolName: "School 1", telephone: "123456", address: "1st street, 1st road"},
  {schoolName: "School 2", telephone: "654321", address: "2nd street, 2nd road"}
];

let telephoneArr = [];
data.forEach(school => Object.keys(school).forEach(function(key, index) {
  if (key === 'telephone') telephoneArr.push(school[key]);
}));

console.log(telephoneArr);
```

Comment: needed to use JS for practice.  Is there a way?

Comment: this **is** JS - just replace  `data` with `table1.data`

Comment: i see, thank you! worked out well on my end.